# Compiling with Py2Exe - Black Box Error

Tags: python, py2exe

When trying to compile a GUI program using Py2Exe, whenever I load the GUI, a black box appears behind it.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your py2exe script, specify `windows=['myscript.py'],` instead of `console=['myscript.py'],`

Like so:

```
setup(
        windows=['myscript.py'],
        options={
                "py2exe":{
                        "unbuffered": True,
                        "optimize": 2,
                }
        }
)
```

See [py2exe List Of Options](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the windows option to Setup rather than the console option.

```
setup(
#  windows = [RPMApp],
  console = [RPMApp, DBMigrate],
  zipfile = 'common.bin',
  options = options,
  data_files = files,
  cmdclass = {'py2exe': FileCollector}
)
```

Here, I actually have the console enabled for debugging, but I'll uncomment the windows option when I finish building for deployment.